# Single splitting from multiple

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I need to split or crop my image into several images. My code is given below which can split an Image into 4 pieces but I am not be able to create 6 or 9 pieces using my code. I am a beginner so unable to find out a solution.

My code is given below:

```
from scipy import misc

# Read the image
img = misc.imread("Imaagi.jpg")
height, width, _ = img.shape

# Cut the image in half
width_cutoff = width // 2
s1 = img[:, :width_cutoff, :]
s2 = img[:, width_cutoff:, :]


# Save each half
misc.imsave("1.jpg", s1)
misc.imsave("2.jpg", s2)

img = misc.imread("1.jpg")
height, width, _ = img.shape
height_cutoff = height // 2

s3 = img[:height_cutoff, :, :]
s4 = img[height_cutoff:, :, :]

misc.imsave("111.jpg", s3)
misc.imsave("222.jpg", s4)
```

The code above first split an image into two parts and then from that two parts it divide that image into 4 parts.But if I need to split it as much as I need like 6,9,15 then how to do this?

This is my image which I need to split into 6 separate boxes:

[image: This is my image which I need to splitt into 6 separate boxes.]

Comment: So, ideally you would write a function that returns you a list of images. You would pass it an input image and then a number of columns and a number of rows into which to split the image?

Comment: Yes..That is exactly I want

Comment: Cool. Try writing a function, and adding in parameters and calling it. Then try adding 2 `for` loops, one over the rows and one over the columns. Try creating an empty list and adding images to it inside the loops.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark. But I am just a beginner. Could you please show me the code so that I can learn it from there?

Comment: Glad to see @mahesh is helping you out. Please be sure to accept (and hopefully upvote) his answer if it helps you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, for non-4 numbers, you need a function to split the number into factors of almost equal size. For 4, you have done it by hand, 2x2. So, the following code would dothe splitting as you wish (works on python 3.6.3, scipy 1.1.0):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import math, cv2
from scipy import misc
import numpy

def getFactors(num):
    """
    Split the input number into factors nearest to its square root. May not be
    the most efficient for large numbers, but will do for numbers smaller than 1000.
    """
    sqt = int(math.sqrt(num))
    if (num % sqt) == 0:
        return (sqt,int(num/sqt))

    num1 = sqt
    num2 = sqt
    while True:
        num1 += 1
        num2 -= 1
        if (num1 >= num) or (num2 <= 0):
            return (num, 1)
        if (num % num1) == 0:
            return (num1, int(num/num1))
        if (num % num2) == 0:
            return (num2, int(num/num2))
    return

def splitImage(img, numsplits):
    """
    Split the input image into number of splits provided by the second argument.
    The results are stored in a numpy array res and returned. The last index of the
    res array indexes the individual parts.
    """
    # Get the factors for splitting. So if the number of splits is 9, then (3,3)
    # or if 6 then (2,3) etc.
    factors = getFactors(numsplits)
    # Height and width of each split
    h = int(img.shape[0] / factors[0])
    w = int(img.shape[1] / factors[1])
    # Handle both color and B&W images
    if img.ndim >= 3:
        size = (h,w,img.shape[2],numsplits)
    else:
        size = (h,w,numsplits)
    # Initialize the result array
    res = numpy.ndarray( size, dtype = img.dtype )
    # Iterate through the number of factors to split the source image horizontally
    # and vertically, and store the resultant chunks
    for i in range(factors[0]):
        for j in range(factors[1]):
            if img.ndim >= 3:
                res[:,:,:,((i*factors[1])+j)] = img[(i*h):((i+1)*h), (j*w):((j+1)*w),:]
            else:
                res[:,:,((i*factors[1])+j)] = img[(i*h):((i+1)*h), (j*w):((j+1)*w)]

    return res

def cropImage(img):
    """
    Detect lines in the image to crop it so that the resultant image can be split well.
    We use here Canny edge detection followed by Hough Line Transform.
    """
    # Convert image to grayscale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # Detect edges and lines
    edges = cv2.Canny(gray, 50, 150, apertureSize = 3)
    lines = cv2.HoughLines(edges, 1, numpy.pi/90, 200)

    min_x = img.shape[0]
    max_x = 0
    min_y = img.shape[1]
    max_y = 0
    # Find the extremal horizontal and vertical coordinates to crop
    for i in range(len(lines[:,0,0])):
        rho = lines[i,0,0]
        theta = lines[i,0,1]
        a = numpy.cos(theta)
        b = numpy.sin(theta)
        x = a*rho
        y = b*rho

        if abs(a) < 1e-06 :
            if min_y > int(y):
                min_y = int(y)
            if max_y < int(y):
                max_y = int(y)
        if abs(b) < 1e-06 :
            if min_x > int(x):
                min_x = int(x)
            if max_x < int(x):
                max_x = int(x)

    return img[min_y:max_y, min_x:max_x, :]

# Read image     
img = misc.imread('tmp.png')
# Crop the image
img = cropImage(img)
# Call the splitter function
res = splitImage(img, 6)
# Save the results to files
for i in range(res.shape[-1]):
    if img.ndim >= 3:
        misc.imsave('res_{0:03d}.png'.format(i),res[:,:,:,i])
    else:
        misc.imsave('res_{0:03d}.png'.format(i),res[:,:,i])
```

**Important note:** If the image size is not divisible by the factors, then some pixels to the right / bottom will be cropped by this code! But it is not very hard to handle this situation.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have tried your code. But I was not getting exactly what I am looking for. I have edited my post and also attached a picture which I need to split.

Comment: Do you want to extract the boxes separated from the background or just split each box into one piece? Because extracting those boxes nicely would take a lot more work than simple slicing.

Comment: That needs a lot more work, since the boxes need to be detected and then split. Maybe it would also be useful if you could also post what you wish to see as the output to the example image you have posted.

Comment: Ok...Please let me know how to remove the border of the main image, incorporate with the code above. As I found that if I remove the order then I am getting exactly what I want using your code above.

Comment: Yes its absolutely works fine for me. I am just a bit curious to know if I want to know how many rectangles are there in my main image then how I will find it out?

Comment: That is a lot more complicated :-). For that one would need to tune the line detection function I wrote a lot more and add more logic to it.

Comment: @ Mahesh thanks a lot for your view.Could you please help me regarding that?

Comment: I will try after a few days and comment here. Right now I am a bit occupied :)

Comment: @paul: It will take time. As I said, it is not that easy. I am trying to look at some possible ways to solve it.