# How can I create three separate image files from this one image file?

Tags: python

[image]

How can I create three separate image files from this one image file?

Answer (score 0):

You can work with slicing arrays if you need to do it often. There already exists a thread about that. Check out [Image processing with single to multiple images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51379338/image-processing-with-single-to-multiple-images)

Comment: but how to get the vertices for slicing? is there a better way to do this?

Comment: The specified thread has already the solution. If you want to implement it in python to automatically crop while recognizing the corners this is a good way to go.